# Showing Firebase records in an HTML web page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query Firebase records in my HTML page, but I haven't found any luck by now.

I am using JavaScript and here is the current code that I have. Is there a proper way to output the records? I understand it is a JSON formatted file.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://ngong-hills.firebaseio.com/Bookings");
ref.orderByChild("Bookings").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
    document.write(snapshot.key());
});
```

Is there anything i am missing??

Comment: Looks like 'why not?' is a good answer in this case (as you not described what you want indeed)

Comment: the code i am using displays an empty page, its kinda not working.because i want all the records for child (Bookings) to be displayed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using very old tutorial, as

1. [initialization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) looks different now, and
2. you do not just [show data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), you show it in case of some change, so you will not see anything in there is no changes

This code works for me

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
    var config = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "crackling-fire-7458.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://crackling-fire-7458.firebaseio.com"
    }
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var ref = app.database().ref('/');

    ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so what do you recomend i do @ArtemDudkin i have var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBrvFpU7AL3efIisDJyQ56giSqc9Gi4dn8",
    authDomain: "ngong-hills.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://ngong-hills.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "gs://ngong-hills.appspot.com"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var ref = new Firebase("https://ngong-hills.firebaseio.com/Bookings");
 ref.orderByChild("Bookings").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.key());

   document.write(snapshot.key());
 });

Comment: do you actually have an answer for this question i asked???  like a real working code that can help me achieve my query

Comment: pleaqse look at (2) - you do not just show data. In your code data will be shown only after "child_added" event (i.e. never) Please look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write